# How to add RecyclerView dependency - gradle 3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I have started with android and Kotlin and I'm having problems to create a **RecyclerView**. So far what I saw is I have a new gradle version and I can't figure out how include the dependency I need.

Below you can see how looks my dependencies on the build.gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}
```

I guess the problem is in the dependen RecyclerView and I cant find how use it.

Comment: Have you tried with this  `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'` ?

Comment: You can still use `compile` in Gradle version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as shown below:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
}
```